# Define two Administrator with different privileges on smart cards

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

Assume a situation in which that you want to distribute a card between two different companies (Let named them *Company-A* and *Company-B*). 
These companies must be able to install or delete their Applets on the card,  but they should not be able to delete the Applet of the other company.

I think there is two solution :

1. Define two *Key Sets* in the ISD (named **KS1** and **KS2**), and define their related privilege for each Key Set in a way to obtain the described conditions.Then give **KS1** to Company-A and **KS2** to Company-B.
2. Adding different *Security Domain*(Named **SD1** and **SD2**) and give the keys of **SD1**(Can it be the ISD?) to Company-A and the keys of **SD2** to Company-B.

**Q1: Which one of above solutions is true? Is there any other solution? if so, how to do it? [In this step, answer of the second part is optional! ;) ]**

**Q2: Using the correct solution, can them see the AID of the other company's Applets in the output of `list` contents command?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** Every security domain has the right to delete any associated applets during any time, therefore solution 1 does not work.

Solution 2 is the right one. Read more in the Global Platform specification abaout Supplementary Security Domain (SSD)

**Q2:** To my knowledge it is not possible to hide any applets and I think there was a similar question in this forum already concerning this topic

Comment: Writing a `SSD` is similar to writing a typical Java Card applet and the differences is : 1- We need to use some of GP APIs in our applet 2- We must give the right privilege to this applet in the installation procedure. Right?

Comment: Creating SSD is independent from a JC applet. you only send APDUs in conformity with GP

Comment: Do you mean that I don't need to upload any _.cap_ file to create a new SSD and the card, itself, will make a new SD on reception of a specific queue of APDU commands using the package of primary SD?!

Comment: no. a security domain is not a java card applet that you upload yourself. its preinstalled, the GP layer will add SSD himself if you tell him that

Comment: Thank you. But what is different key sets for? What is the advantages of having different key set and key indexes in the card?

Comment: Don't pin me down on that, but I think that you prefer to use new indexes and sets to update keys, so people don't get confused about different versions

Comment: I agree with Paul - it is mostly an operational tool. You might want to use different sets of keys while you migrate reader software, for example. But once you have access to a resource, you have the same rights, regardless of the key you are using.

Comment: @mictter Why should I prefer to use different sets of keys while I'm migrating reader software?

Comment: Because if you are having a problem with migration you want to distinguish the error from other errors.

Comment: to make it clear: <key not found> is better than <authentication failed> as the latter could be anything